# Taking T-SQL query into another query and find matches

Tags: sql-server

So I have the following:

```
SELECT 
    data, 
    encrypteddata,
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(encrypteddata)) AS 'decrypteddata'
FROM table
```

Given the key it outputs the original data column, encrypted data column and decrypted data column as a temp column. All good.

What I have been trying to do is get that result, and just make another AS column and say `Match` with true or false if it is a match or not.

I've tried

```
SELECT 
    data, 
    encrypteddata,
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(encrypteddata)) AS 'decrypteddata'
    COUNT(distinct(decrypteddata))
FROM table
WHERE COUNT (distinct(decrypteddata)) > 1 
GROUP BY data
```

This just gives me an error at the first `COUNT` about syntax.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I could do this?

Comment: Would it suffice to count the encrypteddata field instead?  That would simplify the query a little, and it seems like it would give the same result, assuming the DecryptByKey function is deterministic.

Comment: You're missing a single `,` after the `AS 'decrypteddata'` in your second query - that's why you're getting a syntax error.

Comment: You should ALWAYS use a length when converting/casting values.  So use something like varchar(255), to be sure your conversion works successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT 
data, 
encrypteddata,
CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(encrypteddata)) AS 'decrypteddata',
COUNT(distinct(decrypteddata))
FROM table
WHERE COUNT (distinct(decrypteddata)) >1 group by data
```

--Here you have used convert function-In this you have used just varchar without length parameter.So if you actual data is of more than 30 characters it will take only 30 characters and rest will be truncated.So just make sure what would be the length of your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are missing a colon at the end of this line

```
CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(encrypteddata)) AS 'decrypteddata'
```

Also, i dont quite get what are you trying to match, but consider using IF for that

```
SELECT
IF(CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(encrypteddata))=other_data_field, 'true','false') as Match
....
```